# Laravel 4 defining RESTful controllers

Tags: rest, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

So I'm new to the Laravel framework as of v4 and wondering what is the way to create and use RESTful controllers. Reading through the documentation, I'm a bit confused as to the difference between RESTful controllers and Resource controllers.

When defining a RESTful controller, as per the docs, it suggests doing the following in `routes.php`:

```
Route::controller('posts', 'PostController');
```

In the `PostController`, do we define the class methods by prefixing the name of the method with the HTTP verb we should like to use? For example:

```
class PostController extends \BaseController {
    public function getIndex()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

However, it also outlines a way of creating Resource controllers in the `routes.php` file like so:
    Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');

And in `PostController.php` we define methods without prefixing it with the HTTP verb.

```
class PostController extends \BaseController {
    public function index()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

What is the difference between the two? And when do we use one instead of the other, and why?

Also, should we use `Route::controller('posts', 'PostController');` or `Route::resource('posts', 'PostController');` to pass routing to the controller or should we define each route manually, like below:

```
Route::get('/users', 'UserController@index');
Route::get('/users/create', 'UserController@create');
Route::post('/users', 'UserController@store');
Route::get('/users/{id}', 'UserController@show');
Route::get('/users{id}/edit', 'UserController@edit');
Route::put('/users', 'UserController@update');
Route::delete('/users', 'UserController@destroy');
```

Comment: The latter, Route::resource, as per the docs - unless you need more control. :)

Comment: So using `Route::controller('posts', 'PostController');` should not be used to create RESTful controllers? Neither should we prefix the controller methods with the appropriate HTTP verb? I realise the last question is probably not appropriate for this format since it is subjective.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Take this controller as example:

```
<?php

class TestController extends BaseController {

    public function getIndex()
    {
        echo "a";
    }

    public function postSecond($a)
    {
        echo "b";
    }

}
```

In your routes, if you have

```
Route::controller('tests', 'TestController');
```

And execute

```
php artisan routes
```

You'll have:

```
+--------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                        | Name                   | Action                            | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET /tests/index/{v1}/{v2}/{v3}/{v4}/{v5}  |                        | TestController@getIndex           |                |               |
|        | GET /tests                                 |                        | TestController@getIndex           |                |               |
|        | POST /tests                                | tests.store            | TestController@store              |                |               |
|        | GET /tests/{_missing}                      |                        | TestController@missingMethod      |                |               |
+--------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

Laravel inspects the controller and generates routes based on what methods it finds, automatically.

But if you do

```
Route::resource('tests', 'TestController');
```

You'll get this route listing:

```
+--------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                        | Name                   | Action                            | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET /tests                                 |                        | Closure                           |                |               |
|        | GET /tests                                 | tests.index            | TestController@index              |                |               |
|        | GET /tests/create                          | tests.create           | TestController@create             |                |               |
|        | POST /tests                                | tests.store            | TestController@store              |                |               |
|        | GET /tests/{tests}                         | tests.show             | TestController@show               |                |               |
|        | GET /tests/{tests}/edit                    | tests.edit             | TestController@edit               |                |               |
|        | PUT /tests/{tests}                         | tests.update           | TestController@update             |                |               |
|        | PATCH /tests/{tests}                       |                        | TestController@update             |                |               |
|        | DELETE /tests/{tests}                      | tests.destroy          | TestController@destroy            |                |               |
+--------+--------------------------------------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
```

No guessing, Laravel uses a predefined CRUD list of routes, you can remove some of those routes but it won't inspect your controller to build routes for your methods.

You decide what's best for you. But, usually, if your controller is a CRUD one, Route::resource() is a good start, otherwhise you can use Route::controller() or build your routes manually.

EDIT:

There no really why one or why another, is just a matter of design and choice. Some will use none of them, ever. It's just hat `Route::resource()` follows the Rails way of routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html.

Using `Route::resource()` you don't need to create all those methods, but you'll end up with a list of pointless routes, because Laravel always create all of them by default, unless you do:

```
Route::resource('photo', 'PhotoController',
                array('only' => array('index', 'show')));
```

And your list of routes will show only the index and show actions.

Also, if you need some other routes, using `Route::resource()` you'll have to build them manually or work some magic to make them automatic for all your resourceful routes. Using `Route::controller()` everything is automatic, everytime you add a new method, a new route is created for you.

Again, if you have a CRUD controller to build, start by using `Route::resource()`. Otherwise, think about the benefits of one or another in your particular case.

EDIT2:

This is a great article, from Phil Sturgeon (PyroCMS and PHP-FIG), about the benefits of manually build all your routes: http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil.

Comment: I'm not too sure I understand your answer. Why would I use `Route::controller` instead of `Route::resource` if they both achieve the same thing? `Route::controller` seems like a more convoluted process to set up a RESTful controller as it requires breaking convention and prefixing the controller methods with the HTTP verb. Is there any reason to use it over `Route::resource`? If I use `Route::resource` I don't have to have controller methods for index, create, store, show, edit, update and destroy do I? Adding or removing methods to this will reflect in the routes available?

Comment: OK, so as I understand it then, `Route::controller` inspects the controller and generates routes based on what methods it finds, whereas `Route::resource` generates a predefined list of routes available. My question, then, is if I use `Route::resource('posts', 'PostController')` and I add or remove methods to/from `PostController.php`, will Laravel inspect the controller and create or drop routes? Suppose I add a method `archive()` to `PostsController.php` - will Laravel add `/posts/archive/` to my available routes or will I have to specify this manually via `Route::get()`? in routes.php?

Comment: Also, that is an excellent article and I think I will probably define routes manually instead of relying on `Route::controller` or `Route::resource`. I can use `php artisan controller:make {x}` to generate the scaffolding and map to it accordingly in my routes.php file. This seems like a sound practice?

Comment: Laravel will only inspect the controller methods on ´Route::controller´. All routes created by ´Route::resource´ are predefined in the router class. It will not inspect your controller to find new routes. To change that you need to extend that class and replace the Laravel router with your own. `artisan controller:make` is a good generator, sometimes you may need to remove some of the boilerplate code, but it helps a lot when you need a full CRUD controller, or you can use the options to just generate those methods you need.

Comment: OK, that all makes sense now - tyvm :)

Answer (score 6):

@Antonio's answer is good.  Let me say something similar and important a little more concisely.  In routes.php:

```
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

Using the resource method makes Laravel assume CRUD functionality and it only looks for its six, pre-made CRUD methods: index, create, store, show, destroy, etc.  It won't "see" any other, new methods you create there.

```
Route::controller('info', 'InfoController');
```

Using the controller method allows you to create custom methods/pages.  Laravel looks for them when you prepend the method/page name with a HTTP verb.  In your XxxxController.php:

```
class InfoController extends \BaseController {

    public function getFeatures()
    {
        return View::make('info.features');
    }

    public function getContactUs()
    {
        return View::make('info.contact-us');
    }

    public function getPricing()
    {
        return View::make('info.pricing');
    }

}
```