# Required order for specifying restful routes in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, rest, laravel-4, routes, laravel-routing

I'm trying to understand routing in Laravel 4. I read a good [post here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18402298/laravel-4-defining-restful-controllers) and a link to [beware the route to evil](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil), a post about manually specifying routes. I like the idea of specifying my routes manually and having the routes.php act as documentation. But it seems like I need to be cautious about the order of my Routes if I'm going to specify my own instead of using `Route::resource()` If I have the `new` or `create` route before the `show` then I won't be routed to the show because of the variable in URI? The order in which the routes are defined is important right?

```
// This will not work if I try and browse to dogs/new
Route::get('dogs', array('as' => 'dogs', 'uses' => 'DogsController@index'));  
Route::get('dogs/{dogs}', array('as' => 'dog', 'uses' => 'DogsController@show'));
Route::get('dogs/new', array('as' => 'new_dog', 'uses' => 'DogsController@create'));
```

It seems I need to make sure that the `dogs/new` comes before the `dogs/{dogs}` for new to return correctly. I'm not clear on what `{dogs}` does or that's different from `(:any)` or `{any}` I've seen a few different uses in examples and pseudo code. I see that `/new` is the same as `{...}` when the route is before the more specific is the {} like a wildcard in Laravel 4? Is the (:...) the old way?

As an aside I've noticed a different naming convention from some of the examples I've seen when I run `php artisan routes` with a resource route like `Route::resource('photos', 'PhotosController');` The method and named route for post to index to a create a new resource is named photos.store and @store. The method and named route for a link to a form to create a new resource is photos.create and @create. Is that Laravel 4 thing or conventions in other frameworks?

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('dogs/{dogs}', array('as' => 'dog', 'uses' => 'DogsController@show'));
```

The above url expecting a parameter after dogs segment. 
for example: `http://laravel.com/dogs/xyz`, `http://laravel.com/dogs/new`

after dogs url segment, Laravel will accept anything. So, your another routing will never executed for the route parameter.

```
Route::get('dogs/new', array('as' => 'new_dog', 'uses' => 'DogsController@create'));
```

More about route parameters:

http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-parameters

**Resource Controllers**
`Laravel` and `Ruby on rails` support resource full routing. I think, Tailor borrow the resource full routing idea from Ruby on rails.

The following routes will generate if you use resource controller:

```
index
create
store
update
show
edit
destroy
```

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

http://laravel.com/docs/controllers#resource-controllers